# Modifying the service host base addresses without rewriting the application configuration file

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration, app-config, wcf-configuration

I am trying to adjust the host base address prior to launching the WCF service host to add an `instanceName` to the base address:

```
var baseAddresses = Utils<Uri>.EmptyList;

var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var serviceModelGroup = cfg.GetSectionGroup("system.serviceModel") as 
    ServiceModelSectionGroup;

var wcfPortalServiceElement = serviceModelGroup.Services.
    Services[typeof(WcfPortal).FullName];
if (wcfPortalServiceElement != null && wcfPortalServiceElement.Host != null)
{
  baseAddresses = wcfPortalServiceElement.Host
        .BaseAddresses
        .Cast<BaseAddressElement>()
        .Select(e => new Uri(e.BaseAddress + "/" + instanceName, 
            UriKind.Absolute))
        .ToArray();
}
```

The `app.config` file looks as following:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyCompany.Common.Csla.WcfPortal" 
      behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint contract="Csla.Server.Hosts.IWcfPortal"
              binding="customBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="compressed_httpConfig"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/MyAgent" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

**Motivation:** I want to be able to run the same agent process several times on the same machine. Each instance has distinct name (given on the command line), which should be incorporated in the host base address.
Now, this is easy to do if the app.config does not include the baseAddresses collection at all. However, I would like it to be there in case a single agent process is run without being given the instance name.

The problem is that the service host merges the base addresses given in its constructor with those appearing in app.config. Naturally it fails with an exception, because it discovers two addresses with the http scheme.

Also: am I following the mainstream WCF philosophy, when trying to modify the WCF address, depending on a running instance? If I am lost in the labyrinth of hacks - please show the way back to the main road.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking of a real simple approach.  If you already have a method for connecting to an instance if no base address is present, I would remove the base address. Then I would place the base address and the default instance name into the app.config appsetings section.  Then in code combine the base address and instance name given at the command line or if no instance name is given then use DefaultInstance name from appSettings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BaseAddress" value="http://localhost:8001/" />
    <add key="DefaultInstance" value="MyAgent" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And just for full disclosure you can read these values easily with this code.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"]
```

Comment: This is how it works now. I am specifically interested to know whether it is possible to modify the organic WCF configuration programmatically without actually saving it on the disk.